# Array of passwords in authentication api

Tags: authentication, brute-force

I'm doing security labs on portswigger.net. One of the labs asks to avoid authentication. Intercepting the api call I see that payload for authentication is small json:

```
{
 "username": "uname",
 "password": "pwd",
 "": ""
}
```

I was doing my best to complete the lab, but didn't get luck. After giving up I've opened solution provided by portswigger. And here it is:

```
{
 "username" : "carlos",
 "password" : [
    "123456",
    "password",
    "qwerty"
    ...
 ]
}
```

They suggest to put huge password list into the "password" field as an array.
So the question is - how real is this authentication vulnerability? I can't imagine backend algorithm which takes a list of passwords and tries to authenticate user by each password.

Comment: "I can't imagine backend algorithm which takes a list of passwords and tries to authenticate user by each password." Me neither, seems quite unrealistic. With a minimum of input purification the server could get suspicious if an array instead of a plain string gets passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possibility 1: Substring

The backend could be coded to test the saved password as a substring/subelement in the supplied password.

`if $stored_password in $json_password`

That is, unfortunately, not *that* unusual in the history of computing. 20 years ago, I saw sites with similar insecure logic. The idea was to try to "help" the user by being forgiving of types of typos. This requires quite a number of failures of secure practices, but, it can happen. I'm sure that it is very, very unlikely today.

This would apply in your situation if you could pass a string that contains the password but has other characters, too.

### Possibility 2: Truncating

The other unfortunate practice is to truncate the supplied password string to the expected number of allowed characters. So, if your system only allows 8 chars, you can allow a nearly unlimited number of characters in the UI, but truncate it to 8 on the backend.

So, if my password is `thisisareallylongpassword`, the UI will accept it, giving the impression that the system allows secure passwords. But what the system actually processes is `thisisar`.

This would only apply in your situation if the actual password was the first one.

### Possibility 3: Array Parsing

If the portswigger lab is programmed to parse the password array and test each element of the array, then I have never heard of this in any system. If the system is designed to take the string and parse it *like* an array, character by character, then *maybe*, but I'm still having trouble seeing how that would work in practice.